# Installing OFBiz in debug mode hangs

Tags: java, eclipse, ofbiz

I am trying to install OFBiz in debug mode on my Windows 7 machine. I downloaded the OFBiz zip file, extracted it in the folder and then run the following command
`gradelw ofbizDebug`
But it hangs as in the figure below at 91%[image]
The command line has hanged their for last 4 hours or so without any progress and there are no errors either. Can anybody tell me what could be wrong or how to proceed from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think OFBiz does not hang and that you should be able to access and work with it without problems. The Gradle percentage is bit misleading here, it does not reach 100% as long as OFBiz is running.

See also https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/26543a82adf1f8d9a8bec47975e8d87f750c2de2f2da7e242b04a72e@%3Cuser.ofbiz.apache.org%3E

Comment: Thanks @Michael, I am having problem importing obbiz in eclipse. When I import the project after `gradlew eclipse` the project show build errors. I have jdk 1.8 installed which is required for ofbiz 16.11.*

Comment: Hi @Pi-Sigma, this seems to be another topic apart from the original question. Please create another topic for it and provide some more info, e.g. what are the build errors?