# Apache OFBiz installation trouble with BIRT container

Tags: java, apache, installation, ofbiz

I am new to Apache OFBiz. I have downloaded and installing the OFBiz by instructions. I have loaded the data successfully.

But when am running OFBiz using `gradlew` it stopped at birt-container. I have added the console information here.

Build process stopped at 91% with the message of "Started container birt-container" for 5 hours and I have stopped the process. Still no idea why it is stopping here.

```
2017-05-04 11:01:42,143 |main                 |CatalinaContainer             |I| Connector HTTP/1.1 @ 8443 - secure [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol] started.
2017-05-04 11:01:42,143 |main                 |CatalinaContainer             |I| Started Apache Tomcat/8.0.37
2017-05-04 11:01:42,143 |main                 |ContainerLoader               |I| Started container catalina-container
2017-05-04 11:01:42,143 |main                 |ContainerLoader               |I| Starting container birt-container
2017-05-04 11:01:42,143 |main                 |BirtContainer                 |I| Start BIRT container
2017-05-04 11:01:42,152 |main                 |BirtContainer                 |I| Startup BIRT platform
2017-05-04 11:01:43,034 |main                 |BirtContainer                 |I| Create factory object
2017-05-04 11:01:43,052 |main                 |BirtContainer                 |I| Create report engine
2017-05-04 11:01:43,130 |main                 |BirtContainer                 |I| BIRT supported formats: xlsx, postscript, docx, pptx, pdf, ppt, xls_spudsoft, doc, html,
odp, xls, odt, ods
2017-05-04 11:01:43,130 |main                 |ContainerLoader               |I| Started container birt-container
> Building 91% > :ofbiz
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing OfBiz in debug mode hangs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41641328/installing-ofbiz-in-debug-mode-hangs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Gradle percentage is bit misleading here, it does not reach 100% as long as OFBiz is running. I think you just assumed after building the service will be up. Not like that. Once the Service is up it will be in 91%. But the Service has been started. You can access the E-Commerce and other services. Once you are running service get the following URL (ex).

```
localhost:8443/ap/control/main
```

You will be redirected to admin login page. Give user as "admin" and password as "ofbiz". Do the changes and test your data as you want in Accounting, Manufacturing, HR , etc..

Note: After completed your process stop the process using "stopofbiz" shell script file under tools folder. After stop the service you can able to see the build will be reach 100% in service console.

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate to [Installing OfBiz in debug mode hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41641328/installing-ofbiz-in-debug-mode-hangs)

I think OFBiz does not hang and that you should be able to access and work with it without problems. The Gradle percentage is bit misleading here, it does not reach 100% as long as OFBiz is running.

See also https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/26543a82adf1f8d9a8bec47975e8d87f750c2de2f2da7e242b04a72e@%3Cuser.ofbiz.apache.org%3E

Answer (score 0):

Prepare OFBiz:

**Clean all:**
`gradlew cleanAll loadDefault testIntegration`

Note: Depending on your Internet connection speed it might take a long time for this step to complete if you are using OFBiz for the first time as it needs to download all dependencies. So please be patient!

MS Windows: `gradlew cleanAll loadDefault`

Unix-like OS: `./gradlew cleanAll loadDefault`

**Start OFBiz:**

MS Windows: `gradlew ofbiz`

Unix-like OS: `./gradlew ofbiz`

**Reference:** After download http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/ofbiz/apache-ofbiz-16.11.02.zip , unzip, look for
***apache-ofbiz-16.11.02/tools/documentation/README.md.html***